# SQLite Complex Join Query for four tables

Tags: sqlite, join, multiple-tables

I created the following four tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE "Customer" (
      "Customer_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      "First_Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
      "Last_Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
      "Street_Address" TEXT NOT NULL,
      "Apartment_Number" TEXT NOT NULL,
      "City" TEXT NOT NULL,
      "State" TEXT NOT NULL,
      "ZIP" INTEGER NOT NULL,
      "Home_Phone" INTEGER NOT NULL,
      "Mobile_Phone" INTEGER NOT NULL,
      "Other_Phone" INTEGER NOT NULL
      );

   CREATE TABLE "Donut" (
     "Donut_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     "Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
     "Description" TEXT NOT NULL,
     "Unit_Price" FLOAT NOT NULL
     );

   CREATE TABLE "Donut_Order" (
     "Donut_Order_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     "Customer_ID" INTEGER REFERENCES "Customer" ("Customer_ID"),
     "Order_Date" REAL NOT NULL,
     "Notes" TEXT
     );

   CREATE TABLE "Order_Line_Item" (
     "Donut" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Donut" ("Donut_ID"),
     "Donut_Order" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Donut_Order"("Donut_Order_ID"),
     "Qty" INTEGER NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY ("Donut", "Donut_Order")
     );
```

I then inserted the following data (truncated for brevity):

```
INSERT INTO Customer ( First_Name, Last_Name, Street_Address, Apartment_Number, City, State, ZIP, Home_Phone, Mobile_Phone, Other_Phone) VALUES('Alvin','Cressfol','1313 Mockingbird Lane','01','Auburn','AL','36801','+3345550480','3345550480','+3345555423');

INSERT INTO DONUT(Name, Description, Unit_Price) VALUES('Plain','Plain Donut','1.50');
INSERT INTO DONUT(Name, Description, Unit_Price) VALUES('Glazed','Glazed Donut','1.75');
INSERT INTO DONUT(Name, Description, Unit_Price) VALUES('Cinnamon', 'Cinnamon Donut','1.75');
INSERT INTO DONUT(Name, Description, Unit_Price)  VALUES('Chocolate','Chocolate Donut','1.75');
INSERT INTO DONUT(Name, Description, Unit_Price) VALUES('Sprinkle','Sprinkle Donut','1.75');
INSERT INTO DONUT(Name, Description, Unit_Price) VALUES('Gluten-Free','Gluten-Free Donut','2.00');


INSERT INTO Donut_Order (`Customer_ID`,`Order_Date`) VALUES (1,(DATETIME('now')));

INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item VALUES(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item VALUES(1,2,12);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item VALUES(1,3,8);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item VALUES(1,4,8);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item VALUES(1,5,6);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item VALUES(1,6,6);
```

Now I need to complex join to output a line for each Order_Line_Item that occurs for Order_ID = 1. The output needs to be formatted similarly to this:

[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPeb0.jpg)

I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT I.Order_Date ,
ILI.Donut_Order_Number,
substr(C.First_Name," ",C.Last_Name) AS CUSTNAME,
C.Street_Address,
C.CITY,
C.ZIP,
C.Home_Phone,
C.Mobile_Phone,
C.Other_Phone,
C.Apartment_Number,
ILI.Quantity,
ILI.Donut_ID,
D.Name,
D.Description,
D.Unit_Price,
FROM CUSTOMER C
JOIN Donut_Order I ON  C.Customer_ID=I.Customer_ID
JOIN Order_LINE_ITEM ILI ON I.Donut_Order_ID = 1
JOIN DONUT D ON ILI.Donut_ID=D.Donut_ID;
```

My SQLite skills aren't that great, and I having trouble figuring this one out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the error message secret.

Comment: Can break your query down into smaller parts and explain their intend? I would be very interested in the explanation of `substr(C.First_Name," ",C.Last_Name)`, in reference to [substr](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html). And in contrast to `C.First_Name||" "||C.Last_Name`.

Comment: By the way: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Yunnosch - I'm trying to concatenate First_Name and Last_Name as CUSTNAME. I thought I needed substr to do that.

Comment: @CL - The error displayed is "Error: near line 1: near "FROM": syntax error"

Comment: So if you fix the substr mistake, the non-existing `ILI.Donut_Order_Number`, `ILI.Quantity` and `ILI.Donut_ID` and the useless `,` just before the `FROM` - does it then work as you intend it?

Comment: Have you swapped the inserted values for Order_Line_Item."Donut" and Order_Line_Item."Donut_Order"? Looks like you have several orders which all order the same donut. Shouldn't it be one order with several different donuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mentioned syntax error is the `,` just before the `FROM`
and/or the extremely strange use of `substr()`.
Also you should probably fix the references to non-existing columns:

- `ILI.Donut_Order_Number`
- `ILI.Quantity`
- `ILI.Donut_ID`

I propose therefor to use the following code, not saying that it does what you intend it finally to do, but the syntax error(s) and some other obvious errors are gone.

```
SELECT  
    strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", I.Order_Date) as "Order Date",
    ILI.Donut_Order,
    C.First_Name||" "||C.Last_Name AS CUSTNAME,
    C.Street_Address,
    C.Apartment_Number,
    C.CITY,
    C."STATE",
    C.ZIP,
    C.Home_Phone,
    C.Mobile_Phone,
    C.Other_Phone,
    ILI.Qty,
    ILI.Donut,
    D.Name,
    D.Description,
    D.Unit_Price
FROM CUSTOMER        C
JOIN Donut_Order     I   USING (Customer_ID)
JOIN Order_LINE_ITEM ILI ON I.Donut_Order_ID = ILI.Donut_Order
JOIN DONUT           D   ON ILI.Donut        = D.Donut_ID;
```

Output (with `.headers on`):

```
Order Date|Donut_Order|CUSTNAME|Street_Address|Apartment_Number|City|State|ZIP|Home_Phone|Mobile_Phone|Other_Phone|Qty|Donut|Name|Description|Unit_Price
04/17/2017 21:02|1|Alvin Cressfol|1313 Mockingbird Lane|01|Auburn|AL|36801|3345550480|3345550480|3345555423|1|1|Plain|Plain Donut|1.5
04/17/2017 21:02|1|Alvin Cressfol|1313 Mockingbird Lane|01|Auburn|AL|36801|3345550480|3345550480|3345555423|12|2|Glazed|Glazed Donut|1.75
04/17/2017 21:02|1|Alvin Cressfol|1313 Mockingbird Lane|01|Auburn|AL|36801|3345550480|3345550480|3345555423|8|3|Cinnamon|Cinnamon Donut|1.75
04/17/2017 21:02|1|Alvin Cressfol|1313 Mockingbird Lane|01|Auburn|AL|36801|3345550480|3345550480|3345555423|8|4|Chocolate|Chocolate Donut|1.75
04/17/2017 21:02|1|Alvin Cressfol|1313 Mockingbird Lane|01|Auburn|AL|36801|3345550480|3345550480|3345555423|6|5|Sprinkle|Sprinkle Donut|1.75
04/17/2017 21:02|1|Alvin Cressfol|1313 Mockingbird Lane|01|Auburn|AL|36801|3345550480|3345550480|3345555423|6|6|Gluten-Free|Gluten-Free Donut|2.0
04/18/2017 21:02|2|Alvin Cressfol|1313 Mockingbird Lane|01|Auburn|AL|36801|3345550480|3345550480|3345555423|6|6|Gluten-Free|Gluten-Free Donut|2.0
```

Note the following two changes to sample data are needed for a good result with above code.
I fixed the sample data, because I think the order_id and donut_id were accidentally swapped. Using this code:

```
-- fix sample input
delete from Order_Line_Item;

INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item(Donut,Donut_Order,Qty) VALUES(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item(Donut,Donut_Order,Qty) VALUES(2,1,12);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item(Donut,Donut_Order,Qty) VALUES(3,1,8);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item(Donut,Donut_Order,Qty) VALUES(4,1,8);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item(Donut,Donut_Order,Qty) VALUES(5,1,6);
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item(Donut,Donut_Order,Qty) VALUES(6,1,6);
```

I also added a second order, for better testing depth:

```
-- prepare the use of two orders
delete from Donut_Order;

-- use two orders, for better testing
INSERT INTO Donut_Order (`Customer_ID`,`Order_Date`) VALUES (1,(DATETIME('now')));
INSERT INTO Donut_Order (`Customer_ID`,`Order_Date`) VALUES (1,(DATETIME('now', '+1 day')));
INSERT INTO Order_Line_Item(Donut,Donut_Order,Qty) VALUES(6,2,6);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was absolute gold.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the syntax errors, there is no join between the `Order_Line_Item` and `Donut_Order` tables. So you will get combinations with all order line items, even those that do not match the order you want.

The ON clause in the joins should be used only for the actual join conditions. To filter the results further, you should use WHERE instead (this makes the meaning clearer, and you will more easily notice that some join condition is missing):

```
SELECT ...
FROM Customer        C
JOIN Donut_Order     I   USING (Customer_ID)
JOIN Order_Line_Item ILI ON I.Donut_Order_ID = ILI.Donut_Order
JOIN Donut           D   ON ILI.Donut        = D.Donut_ID
WHERE I.Donut_Order_ID = 1;
```

(If you ensure that matching columns have the same name, you can use the simpler USING clause. Your column are inconsistent; some use the `_ID` suffix and some do not.)